# How to convert CSS to SCSS every time?

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm

I'm a full stack developer that uses sass (.scss) for styling. However, my backend crew, when they have to make front end changes, use css because they are comfortable with it.

I have to convert the css to scss every time manually or else I will overwrite their changes. Is there a way to update my scss file to pull in css changes automatically?

My IDE is PhpStorm (if that helps anybody)
SASS version 3.4.24

Comment: "I will overwrite their changes" - where are they putting these changes?  Presumably the only thing you have in version control is the SCSS?

Comment: Tell them to use SCSS, there is no reason for them not to use it. if the front end devs decided that SCSS is what they are going to use, then others should conform. this is like `well i like php, but our stack is in nodeJS, but im gonna do PHP anyway`

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth  They are putting them in the css file directly

Comment: CSS is valid SCSS, so if they just commit their changes into the uncompiled SCSS, everything should be fine.

Comment: @Christoph: I guess the teams are working in two different projects. Front end working with front end project and copying the css and js to back end project.

Comment: @Christoph In a perfect world yes. But lets pretend these are experienced programmers (10yrs + ) who are stuck in their ways and won't listen to a mid level (5 yrs) programmer

Comment: Then it sounds like you're trying to solve a social problem with a technical solution - veering off-topic for SO, but this is something for your manager to solve.

Comment: I agree with Oliver. They can't be very experienced (or at least professional), if they are jeopardising the whole development process by being stubborn... Try to sell them the advantages of using the same code base like the frontend team does to increase efficiency.

Comment: You only have two options here: talk to your superior, explain the benefits compared to the minimal impact it has on what they do (they simply add their code inside some files with `.scss` intead of doing the same in files with `.css` extension. If that's not achievable in your current company, it's really not in your best interest to be there. And that's your second option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a plugin for PHPStorm to do that; you might have to make one yourself. But even if you do, the SCSS it'd produce probably wouldn't be much better than the CSS you already have. It's silly to convert to SCSS only to compile back to CSS. The whole point of SCSS is so that you don't have to write CSS.

You could convert the CSS to SCSS with sites like [this one](http://css2sass.herokuapp.com). Again, results will probably not be much better than if you just kept it CSS.

My solution would be to split the CSS file. One part would be for the stubborn devs, while the other one is the CSS compiled from the SCSS you like to use. So, they can work in CSS, and you can work in SCSS.

You probably need a workplace solution before a technical one.

Comment: Yes, that is how I set it up. One CSS file, One SCSS. The SCSS compiles to CSS upon save via a plugin. So what you're saying is that I have to continue to covert CSS to SCSS every time until an acceptable workplace solution has been found?

Comment: @JDub okay, then I mean 3 files. 1 CSS for the dev who don't write SCSS, 1 SCSS, and 1 CSS for the SCSS to compile to.